# Freebase: working with "namespace-prefix key" Json Object

Tags: json, freebase

I have made a request to freebase API, and the query is:

```
{
  "id" : "/m/01f8mn",
  "key" : [{
    "namespace" : "/wikipedia/en_id",
    "value" : null
  }],
  "key" : [{
    "namespace" : "/authority/mobygames/game",
    "value" : null
  }]  
}​
```

And I got the answer from Freebase:

```
{
  "code":          "/api/status/ok",
  "result": {
    "id": "/m/01f8mn",
    "key": [{
      "namespace": "/wikipedia/en_id",
      "value":     "213502"
    }],
    "ns0:key": [{
      "namespace": "/authority/mobygames/game",
      "value":     "prince-of-persia"
    }],
    "ns1:key": [{
      "namespace": "/authority/giantbomb/game",
      "value":     "61-2561"
    }]
  },
  "status":        "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache03.p01.sjc1:8101;2012-05-20T18:37:04Z;0060"
}
```

As you can notice, there is a "namespace prefix" key in the result ("ns0:key", "ns1:key")

The question is: how can I handle this with Javascript Object? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

When accessing properties with special characters in the name, access it as you would an associative array property:

```
yourObject.result["ns0:key"]
```

Since the namespace and value properties are stored inside of an object that is the first index of an array, to access the namespace and value, use the following syntax:

```
yourObject.result["ns0:key"][0].namespace
yourObject.result["ns0:key"][0].value       // contains "prince-of-persia"

yourObject.result["ns1:key"][0].namespace
yourObject.result["ns1:key"][0].value       // contains "61-2561"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initial query isn't valid JSON (the two "key" keys will overwrite each other), so I suspect there's an intermediary software layer involved (perhaps Freebase's query editor?).

If it would help to be able to control the prefixes (they're not really namespaces), you can make them up yourself to suit you.  Use "key" and "other:key" or whatever scheme works for you.  You could also re-write the query using the |= operator so you can specify both namespaces in a single key clause (e.g. "key":[{"namespace|=" :[ns1,ns2]}]).

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( key in freebaseResult.result ) {
  var i, resultArray = freebaseResult.result[key];

  for ( i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++ ) {
    alert( resultArray[i].namespace + ": " + resultArray[i].value );
  }
}
```